# Solve $(x^3+e^y)y'=3x^2$. Help me please I can't solve it.

Tags: calculus

Solve  $(x^3+e^y)y'=3x^2$. Help me please I can't solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by solve? Find an expression for $y$?

Comment: yes, find y=y(x)

Comment: find y=y(x), solve equations

Comment: Well this is nonlinear, and cannot be separated. According to Wolfram: $y(x)=W(e^{-c_1}x^3) + c_1$, where $W(z)$ is the Lambert W-Function.

Comment: sovle $(x^3+e^y)dy=3x^2dx$

Comment: The change $u=x^3$ leads to a linear ODE considering $u(y)$ as the unknown function. The result is $x(y)$. Then, the Inversion to find $y(x)$ involves the LambertW function.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $e^{-y}$:
$$
 x^3 e^{-y} y' + y' = 3 x^2 e^{-y}
$$
Rearrange this to yield:
$$
y' = \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^3 e^{-y}\right)\, ,
$$
Or:
$$
y(x) = C + x^3 e^{-y(x)}
$$
As noted above, the solution to this for $y(x)$ involves the Lambert $W$ function:
$$
y(x) = C + W\left(e^{-C} x^3\right)\, .
$$

The [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) cannot be expressed in terms of more elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x^3$. Then, $\frac{du}{dx}=3x^2$. $\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{y'}{3x^2}$.

The expression is,
$$y'=\frac{3x^2}{x^3+e^y}$$
$$\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{1}{u+e^y}$$

Let $v=u+e^y$. Then, $\frac{dv}{du}=1+e^y\frac{dy}{du}$.
$$\frac{\frac{dv}{du}-1}{e^y}=\frac1v$$
$$\frac{\frac{dv}{du}-1}{v-u}=\frac1v$$
$$v\frac{dv}{du}-v=v-u$$
$$v\frac{dv}{du}=2v-u$$
$$\frac{dv}{du}=2-\frac uv$$
Let $v=ku$. Then, $\frac{dv}{du}=k+u\frac{dk}{du}$.
$$k+u\frac{dk}{du}=2-\frac1k$$
$$\int \frac{dk}{2-k-\frac1k}=\int\frac{du}{u}$$

Comment: Can you help me? Solve $(x^2+y^2+1)dy+xydx=0$ I can't sovle it

Comment: $(x^2+y^2+1)dy+xydx=0$ I can't sovle it

Comment: @Tuanlee You should ideally post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

suppose we make two change of variables $$t = x^3, u = e^y \to dt = 3x^2 dx,\  du = udy \tag 1$$  now the differential equation $$(x^3 + e^y) dy = 3x^2 dx $$ becomes $$(t+u)\frac{du}{u} = dt $$ which we will rewrite as forced linear equation in $t,$ that is, $$\frac{dt}{du} = \frac{t+u}u=1+\frac t u \tag 2$$ now, $(2)$ has the general solution $$ t = u \ \ln u+Cu\tag 3$$ going back to the original variables, we get $$x^3=ye^y+Ce^y. $$